# Bloomberg API Login without using Bloomberg Anywhere

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

As you may know the BLPAPI core developer guide (https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf) is not very intuitive and I was not able find a way to connect and authenticate without using the Bloomberg Anywhere Application.

I'm currently looking to develop an application that will run automatically on its own everyday at a specific time and would like to have this application to authenticate itself with Bloomberg and connect to the API.

Many thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible for a Bloomberg Anywhere user - however if you close the terminal on the machine where your script is running and you don't open Bloomberg on another device (PC or mobile), the API should remain available for a few days. As soon as you launch Bloomberg on your mobile the API will be disconnected on your PC.

Comment: on an open bloomberg terminal u may try using a vbscript to log into bloomberg before opening your excel with api. 
however on a bloomberg anywhere you will be asked for a token / otp after entering your login credentials

Answer (score 2):

Justin, authenticating against the BLP API requires one of a few options to be in place. If you're only considering something around the Bloomberg (Professional) Terminal then you need to have a valid 'token' in place. When you light up a Bloomberg Terminal it creates a token and makes a BLP API 'delivery point' available on localhost:8194. When you log out of the Terminal the token remain valid and then delivery point remains intact. The token gets invalidated in two circumstances, either timeout (not even sure it will last overnight), and, the Bloomberg user logging in somewhere else (including on the Bloomberg phone app).

I should also say, that your application use case is constrained by licensing, in that you can only write display applications (as defined by exchange rules).

What some Bloomberg customers resort to if they have challenges around 24/7 applications, and, only have Bloomberg Terminals, is that they buy something called a Server API (SAPI). It allows a client/server pattern to be developed whereby the server portion can login in with its own credentials (application name), and, the client portion authenticates with the Terminal token/user. So, you could write the server component collecting data 24/7 but only delivers the  analytics/results, etc when the Bloomberg Terminal users logs in.

If you're looking for something a little more systematic/autonomous then as a customer you should look at the Bloomberg Enterprise products such as B-PIPE, where the above need not apply, and you have a much more liberal accommodation of patterns.

As with all things finance, the devil is in the detail.. and depending on whether you're looking at exchange traded data or OTC, various rules and fees will apply.

Good luck